# How do I set up unit tests in Swift?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, swift

I'm having trouble adding unit tests to a Swift project of mine, so I created a fresh Xcode test project with a stripped-down version of my class:

```
class SimpleClass {
    let x: String

    init(x: String) {
        self.x = x
    }

    convenience init(dict: Dictionary<String, String>) {
        self.init(x: dict["x"]!)
    }
}
```

Then I created a simple test case:

```
import XCTest
import TestProblem

class TestProblemTests: XCTestCase {
    func testExample() {
        // This is an example of a functional test case.
        XCTAssertEqual(SimpleClass(x: "foo"), SimpleClass(dict: ["x": "foo"]))
    }

}
```

I had to import the project itself (`import TestProblem`) to fix unresolved identifier errors for `SimpleClass`.

However, when I try to run tests, I get the following compiler error:

```
Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments
```

What am I missing here? The calls to init work fine outside of the `XCTAssertEqual` call, even within the test file.

On a hunch, I also tried:

```
    let x = SimpleClass(x: "foo")
    let y = SimpleClass(dict: ["x": "foo"])
    XCTAssertEqual(x, y)
```

When I do that, I get this error:

```
Cannot convert the expression's type 'Void' to type 'SimpleClass'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to define your param explicitely ? Like this :

```
let x : SimpleClass = SimpleClass(x: "foo")
let y : SimpleClass = SimpleClass(dict: ["x": "foo"])
XCTAssertEqual(x, y)
```

Comment: Hmm, that fixes the problem. I wonder why the explicit annotations are necessary.

Comment: You're right normally it have to work without explicit annotations. It's look like a bug for me so you can report it to apple. Xcode is in beta2 so it's not yet perfect.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer - I'll report the issue.

Comment: Additionally, SimpleClass should be equatable